# Throuble when build an apk into phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I´m trying compile a apk into phonegap cli, my application was writting in jquery e jquery mobile.
When I compile at phonegap, run fine at one point, but go back to logon page.

When I´m run at localhost:3000 almost things work fine, but suddently my application receive a error like this:

jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)

I seach at my code and not found, anything about this.

Someone may help me?

Thanks advanced by your time.

Comment: At javascript code I have a follow sequence:

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
In my code, I had a data load inside a form   and inside a back button.
When I pressed the back button the form was trying to submit the data and I could not. The html returned error 404.
Thanks to everyone who has read and tried to understand my problem.